# WLExcludePathOrMimeType issue with Apache 2.2.25 and Weblogic 12c

Tags: apache, apache2, weblogic, weblogic12c, apache2.2

I am facing issue when trying to add exclusions using WLExcludePathOrMimeType for weblogic module in Apache Web Server 2.2.25. I am using Weblogic 12c. Following is the excerpt from the httpd.conf.

```
<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
    WebLogicHost <host_name>
    WebLogicPort 9001
    MatchExpression *.jsp
    MatchExpression *.controller
    MatchExpression /dummy/*
    WLExcludePathOrMimeType *.json
    WLExcludePathOrMimeType *.html
    WLExcludePathOrMimeType *.png
    HungServerRecoverSecs 3600
    ConnectTimeoutSecs 25
    ConnectRetrySecs 2
    Debug OFF
</IfModule>
```

The problem is, for the exclusion it only excludes the last entry i.e. *.png in this case. I have tried giving comma separated list like

```
WLExcludePathOrMimeType *.json,*.html,*.png
```

In this case, it only picks up the first entry i.e. *.json. I am not sure if it's a bug with the mod_wl plugin or there's a problem with the syntax. Any help/workaround would be appreciated.

Just to add, WLExcludePathOrMimeType with comma separated list works fine with IIS as Web Server and Weblogic combination.

Comment: Solved the issue by using a separate '<Location>' tag.

Comment: If you want you can post your solution as an answer and mark it as such (just so people know the question is not still open).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding a separate Location tag in httpd.conf

```
<Location /dummy>
    SetHandler weblogic-handler
    WLExcludePathOrMimeType *.json,*.html,*.png
</Location>
<IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
    WebLogicHost <host_name>
    WebLogicPort 9001
    MatchExpression *.jsp
    MatchExpression *.controller
    MatchExpression /dummy/*
    HungServerRecoverSecs 3600
    ConnectTimeoutSecs 25
    ConnectRetrySecs 2
    Debug OFF
</IfModule>
```

Interestingly, in the documentation of old version of weblogic plugin, it's actually mentioned that WLExcludePathOrMimeType takes comma separated list (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/plugins/plugin_params.html#1143055). While in the newer documentation, it has been skipped (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/plugins/plugin_params.html#wp1143055)